Avoiding double for loops with Polars?
I am trying to use Polars to determine revenue forecast for many products. I have these product names and prices and current revenues based on these prices. Some of these products' revenues are not direct multiplication of quantity and prices but involve a complicated function (distributor percentage etc and more) so I have  created a separate function for that. I want to simulate 50 different scenarios of prices and apply these to the existing product portfolio to determine range of revenues etc. How can I do this using Polars without using for loops?
Specifically, I want to search for the exact product name in the column name of the price dataframe and then for each of the product names in the main dataframe create an updated price column in the main dataframe corresponding to the prices in price dataframe. This will be my first scenario. I will save this scenario as scenario1. This way I want to create as many scenarios as there are rows in the prices dataframe. How do I apply this using Polars without using for loops please?
Thanks in advance.
I am new to polars and haven't been successful in this without using for loops in pandas.

Update:
here is my main_df:
main_df = pl.from_repr("""
┌─────┬───────┐
│ xxx ┆ price │
│ --- ┆ ---   │
│ str ┆ str   │
╞═════╪═══════╡
│ A   ┆ 100   │
│ B   ┆ 150   │
│ C   ┆ 200   │
│ D   ┆ 250   │
│ A   ┆ 230   │
└─────┴───────┘
""")

here is my pixies_df:
pixies_df = pl.from_repr("""
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ A   ┆ B   ┆ C   ┆ D   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 110 ┆ 160 ┆ 210 ┆ 260 │
│ 120 ┆ 170 ┆ 220 ┆ 270 │
│ 130 ┆ 180 ┆ 230 ┆ 280 │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘
""")

here is my expected output:
shape: (5, 5)
┌─────┬───────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ xxx ┆ price ┆ 0   ┆ 1   ┆ 2   │
│ --- ┆ ----- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ str ┆ i64   ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═══════╪═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ A   ┆ 100   ┆ 110 ┆ 120 ┆ 130 │
│ B   ┆ 150   ┆ 160 ┆ 170 ┆ 180 │
│ C   ┆ 200   ┆ 210 ┆ 220 ┆ 230 │
│ D   ┆ 250   ┆ 260 ┆ 270 ┆ 280 │
│ A   ┆ 230   ┆ 110 ┆ 120 ┆ 130 │
└─────┴───────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘

num_rows = pixies_df.height
def transform_column(col_name, col_values):
    return [f"{col_name}-{i}-{col_values[i]}" for i in range(num_rows)]

transformed_data = {col: transform_column(col, pixies_df[col].to_list()) for col in pixies_df.columns}

pixies_df_transformed = pl.DataFrame(transformed_data)

print(pixies_df_transformed)

shape: (3, 5)
┌───────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┐
│ index     ┆ A       ┆ B       ┆ C       ┆ D       │
│ ---       ┆ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---     │
│ str       ┆ str     ┆ str     ┆ str     ┆ str     │
╞═══════════╪═════════╪═════════╪═════════╪═════════╡
│ index-0-0 ┆ A-0-110 ┆ B-0-160 ┆ C-0-210 ┆ D-0-260 │
│ index-1-1 ┆ A-1-120 ┆ B-1-170 ┆ C-1-220 ┆ D-1-270 │
│ index-2-2 ┆ A-2-130 ┆ B-2-180 ┆ C-2-230 ┆ D-2-280 │
└───────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┘

after this i want to extract the prices into main_df. Can you help please?
Also , this is a toy example. The retail HQ mimght contain more than 100000 SKUs (products) and price scenarios can exceed thousand of rows so a cartesian product using for loops is not efficient.
i am adding more details here in the main question: here i am joining the two dfs (it crashes the system for the actual rows so i took smaller size) and then i am using a for loop for applying the revenue function over each subset. I am sure there is a better polars way to do this? Thanks.
'''python
Get integer-like columns starting with 'column_'
integer_columns = [col for col in aa.columns if col.startswith('simprice_')]

# Define a function that processes each column
def process_column(col):
    subset = aa.select(non_integer_columns + [pl.col(col)])
    # Rename 'column_n' to 'underlying_price'
    #print(subset.columns)
return subset.rename({col: 'new_price'})

# Use a list comprehension with map to apply the function to     each column
subsets = list(map(process_column, integer_columns))
changes=[]
for subset in subsets:
# Calculate values and update the subset
updated_subset = revenue_function(subset)
changes.append(sum(updated_subset['revenues']))
print(changes)

def revenue_function(prices_df):
    # Extract prices
    prices = prices_df['price']
    price_adjusted = prices * np.random.uniform(0.9, 1.1,len(prices))  # Random adjustment between 90%-110%

    norm_dist_factor = norm.cdf(price_adjusted / np.mean(prices))  # Normalize prices and apply CDF
price_to_revenue_ratio = 1 + norm_dist_factor * np.random.uniform(0.8, 1.2)  # Further randomization


revenues = price_adjusted * price_to_revenue_ratio

noise = np.random.normal(0, 0.05, len(prices))  # Small random noise
revenues = revenues * (1 + noise)

revenues = np.round(revenues)
prices_df.with_columns(revenues = pl.Series(revenues))
return prices_df

'''

please provide a reproducible example

The reproducible example could show how you do it using for loops in pandas (with a minimal dataset), that would make it a whole lot easier for someone to suggest how to do this without for loops.

Can you also explain why you want to avoid for loops, if possible? E.g. if there's a specific issue with for loops, people will better understand what to recommend instead.


transpose() to convert pixies_df rows to columns.
join() to link it to main_df.

main_df.join(
    pixies_df
    .transpose(
        include_header=True,
        header_name="xxx",
        column_names = list(map(str, range(pixies_df.height)))
    ),
    on="xxx"
)

┌─────┬───────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ xxx ┆ price ┆ 0   ┆ 1   ┆ 2   │
│ --- ┆ ---   ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ str ┆ str   ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═══════╪═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ A   ┆ 100   ┆ 110 ┆ 120 ┆ 130 │
│ B   ┆ 150   ┆ 160 ┆ 170 ┆ 180 │
│ C   ┆ 200   ┆ 210 ┆ 220 ┆ 230 │
│ D   ┆ 250   ┆ 260 ┆ 270 ┆ 280 │
│ A   ┆ 230   ┆ 110 ┆ 120 ┆ 130 │
└─────┴───────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘


Perhaps you could reshape your data with unpivot() + .pivot()
(pixies_df
  .with_row_index()
  .unpivot(index="index", variable_name="xxx")
  .pivot(on="index", index="xxx")
)

shape: (4, 4)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ xxx ┆ 0   ┆ 1   ┆ 2   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ str ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ A   ┆ 110 ┆ 120 ┆ 130 │
│ B   ┆ 160 ┆ 170 ┆ 180 │
│ C   ┆ 210 ┆ 220 ┆ 230 │
│ D   ┆ 260 ┆ 270 ┆ 280 │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘

Adding to main_df would then be a LEFT JOIN.
main_df.join(
   pixies_df
    .with_row_index()
    .unpivot(index="index", variable_name="xxx")
    .pivot(on="index", index="xxx"),
   on = "xxx",
   how = "left"
)

shape: (5, 5)
┌─────┬───────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ xxx ┆ price ┆ 0   ┆ 1   ┆ 2   │
│ --- ┆ ---   ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ str ┆ str   ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═══════╪═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ A   ┆ 100   ┆ 110 ┆ 120 ┆ 130 │
│ B   ┆ 150   ┆ 160 ┆ 170 ┆ 180 │
│ C   ┆ 200   ┆ 210 ┆ 220 ┆ 230 │
│ D   ┆ 250   ┆ 260 ┆ 270 ┆ 280 │
│ A   ┆ 230   ┆ 110 ┆ 120 ┆ 130 │
└─────┴───────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘


Jqurious and Roman Pekar, Many many thanks to both of you . I appreciate the help. While the solution helps to some extent, as i mentioned in my question, I need to then take subsets of this main_df and then apply a complicated business logic function over it. This becomes cumbersome especially where there are more than 300000 rows acrross pixies and main_df. The join itself takes some time and then applying a foo on each subset of main_df takes a lot more time. I am thinking I should perhaps try lazydf ( i am still learning) or go any database route.

If you give a more realistic example then people will be able to give more appropriate answers. i.e. What subsets? What business logic function? How are you "applying" it? (And yes, you should use LazyFrames.)

how can i give more codes ? If i paste it in response here there is not enough space. Thank you.

You can edit your original question - or perhaps create a new one.

Thanks @jqurious. I have edited the original question.
